# Как ключу и значению ключа присвоить содержимое инпутов?

Tags: javascript

```
    let mas = {//пустой объект
       };
        let out4 = '';//пустая переменная
     let u4 = document.querySelector('.out4');//блок
       let f1 = document.querySelector('.f-1');//первый инпут
        let f2 = document.querySelector('.f-2');//второй инпут
   let button = document.querySelector('.button');//кнопка
      button.onclick = () => {
      let ff = f1.value;//присвоил переменной содержимое инпута
      let ff1 = f2.value;//присвоил переменной содержимое 2 инпута
       for (let key in mas) {
    out4 += key[ff] + ':' + mas[ff1] + '<br>';//пытался присвоить ключу содержимое инпута и значению ключа пытался присвоить содержимое второго инпута
   }
       console.log(mas);
       console.log(out4);
       u4.innerHTML = out4;//
         };
     на сайт выводит undefined:undefined 
     в консоль тоже самое
```

Comment: mas[ff] = ff1; вот так выводит без цикла в консоль а на сайт [object,object]

Comment: Для того, чтобы использовать [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) у объекта должны быть заданы свойства, а он определен как пустой объект.

Comment: Даже так не работает.Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в первый инпут вводился ключ. а во второй инпут вводился значение ключа и потом  при клике ,все это выводилось в блок

Comment: Так вроде должно заработать тоже `mas[ff] = ff1; for (let key in mas) {out4 += key + ':' + mas[key] + '<br>';}` Без HTML хоть и гадать не охота.

Answer (score -2):

Так вроде должно заработать тоже mas[ff] = ff1; for (let key in mas) {out4 += key + ':' + mas[key] + '
';} Без HTML хоть и гадать не охота.